# Debugging Node/Express RESTful API with node-inspector

Tags: node.js, rest, debugging, express, node-inspector

I have seen many question about debugging a Node/Express application, but, it seem a node web application, not a RESTful server.

I have built a simple server, and it work perfect when start server with command `node server.js`. I can use Postman, or some other tools to invoke a GET/POST request.

After installing the `node-inspector` module, when I start a node-inspector debug with command `node-debug server.js`, it show me a webpage at `http://127.0.0.1:8080/?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858` with inspector window.

Then, I use postman to invoke request again (which has invoked successfully earlier), but it show me a `404 error`: `Cannot GET /api/v1/user/login`.

How can make a request to debugging server?

Comment: That's probably because when you start your debugger, the execution of `server.js` is paused and the REST server is not really up and running. Try to resume the execution (the pause or play button) and instead set a breakpoint.

Comment: Nope, I has resumed the execution.

Comment: Which version of NI you use? (0.11.0 released with network debugging. This hypothetically can cause some problems. Can you try 0.10.*?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution: Do not use node-debug *.js directly. Instead, open two terminals in your project. For example, I want to debug server-3.js, like the pictures down here. In one terminal, use node-inspector for debugging listening, and another use node --debug server-3.js

[image]

[image]

after sending a request on postman:
[image]

you can see your debugging situation in your node-inspector window listening on port 5858:

[image]

I believe this is what you want to achieve.

The latest update is that you can also resort to vscode, which has a plugin called "Debugger for Chrome" that has the debug function you want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`nodedev`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodedev)

1) Install `nodedev`:

```
sudo npm install -g nodedev
```

2) Start your server:

```
nodedev server.js
```

3) Visit the page [`http://127.0.0.1:7001/debug?port=7000`](http://127.0.0.1:7001/debug?port=7000) to debug...

4) ...

5) Profit!

**Bonus**: Your server will automatically restart when changes are detected!

Answer (score 0):

Use node-inspector instead of node-debug (comes in the same module)
In one terminal execute:
`node-inspector`
In another terminal execute 
`node --debug server.js`

Answer (score 0):

Note that --debug option is deprecated. --inspect is preferred. Otherwise you will get a warning/error.

(node:11524) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.